# Inject embedded js/css file into Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, embedded-resource, swashbuckle

One can include js/css by placing them in `/wwwroot` and then using the `InjectJavascript` and `InjectStylesheet` options.

But how can I instead inject a file that exists as an embedded resource? It used to be possible (if I remember correctly), but I can't find out how to do it for the AspNetCore version of Swashbuckle.

(I'm not asking how to embed a file, but rather how to tell Swashbuckle to use it.)

Answer (score 1):

In Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, the secret behind SwaggerUIOptions's `InjectJavascript` and `InjectStylesheet` is that they are both *extensions*. When you pull the curtain behind what they do, they build up and append their html elements to the SwaggerUIOptions `HeadContent` property, which is what actually gets injected for additional content being added to the Swagger generated html.

This means its easy to create your own extensions that do the same thing, but inject *raw* styles or scripts.

Here's an example that does just that:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Injects additional CSS styles into the index.html page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">The options being extended.</param>
    /// <param name="content">The content of the &lt;style&gt; tag.</param>
    /// <param name="media">The target media - i.e. the link "media" attribute</param>
    public static void InjectRawStylesheet(this SwaggerUIOptions options, string content, string media = "screen")
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(options.HeadContent);
        builder.AppendLine($"<style media='{media}' type='text/css'>");
        builder.AppendLine(content);
        builder.AppendLine("</style>");
        options.HeadContent = builder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Injects additional JavaScript files into the index.html page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">The options being extended.</param>
    /// <param name="content">The content of the &lt;script&gt; tag.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The script type - i.e. the script "type" attribute</param>
    public static void InjectRawJavascript(this SwaggerUIOptions options, string content, string type = "text/javascript")
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(options.HeadContent);
        builder.AppendLine($"<script type='{type}'>");
        builder.AppendLine(content);
        builder.AppendLine("</script>");
        options.HeadContent = builder.ToString();
    }
```

For using these extensions to inject an embedded resource, it would look something like this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.InjectRawJavascript(MyProject.Properties.Resources.MyEmbeddedResource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the Swashbuckle UI in asp.net core, as you said, we need to use the SwaggerUIOptions's `InjectJavascript` and `InjectStylesheet` options.

For example, I create a Asp.net 6 application with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6

[image]

Then, add the css and javascript fille in the `wwwroot` folder.
[image]

Finally, in the program.cs file, enable Static File Middleware and inject the css and javascript file as below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/css/custom.css");
    c.InjectJavascript("/swagger-ui/js/CustomJavaScript.js");
});
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! But that shows how to reference files on disk. I was asking how to use an **embedded resource**. I've since discovered it's not possible - that feature is not available in the "core" version of swashbuckle (it was available in the older pre-core version). Other people who might want to use files on disk will find your screenshots very helpful, thanks.